# ASP MVC 3 field validation of HTML

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a field that will need to ALLOW HTML. It's 100% valid and okay. When I post back from my application I get the following message:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (PowerSource.Text[0]="<p>A control im...").
```

To stop validation I added to my class as follows:

```
public class PowerSource
{
    [System.Web.Mvc.AllowHtml] 
    public string[] Text { get; set; }
}
```

}

The problem is that it doesn't seem to work. I have done this for other fields and I believe it works okay. But not for the field above.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Do I need to mark this field as a data member or something like that?

Please note that I am using MVC3 and I understand validation is a bit different in this version.

Comment: Just to be sure - you want to use a string array from values posted from a form? How are you delimiting/binding these?

Comment: The string array part seems to be working okay. I use @Model.PowerSource.Text[@index] and that seems to work fine. It's just when I add HTML that the problems start.

Comment: I am not sure if this makes a difference but my PowerSource class is called as part of one of a few classes in a viewmodel passed to the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property you have decorated with the `[AllowHtml]` attribute is an array (`string[]`). It should be a simple string property for this to work:

```
[AllowHtml] 
public string Text { get; set; }
```

Then in the view you could have a corresponding input field allowing the user to enter anything:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Text)
```

and finally when you submit to the following action there shouldn't be an exception:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(PowerSource model)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  However I need an array string as the data I send to my view can have any number of Text areas. My code works fine if I add [ValidateInput(false)] to the controller and unless you have any suggestion then I think this might be my only choice.

Comment: @Marie, you could define a custom class: `public class TextModel { [AllowHtml]public string Text { get; set; } }` and then have you main model take a collection of this `TextModel` as property: `public class PowerSource { public TextModel[] Texts { get; set; } }`. Then in the view you would generate the textareas binding to this child model. Note that `ValidateInput(false)` disables input validation for the entire request and not only for the properties you would like.

Comment: That seems like a very good idea. I will check this out. Thank you for your help. I will mark your answer as accepted. Have a great day.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add [ValidateInput(false)] in your controller, don't know if you can do this on the Model but it work for me in the controller.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ViewResult Edit(Object obj)
{
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe it's now different in MVC3 and that's why I was trying to do the per field validation. Your suggestion does fix the problem but I would really like to do it on the field only. thanks

Comment: I don't know about the model attribute but it work just fine in my MVC3 project's controller.

Comment: The model attribute allows you to do the validation at a granular level. It's a new feature in MVC3. This is the feature I was trying to use.

Comment: like in this link : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2010/11/09/mvc3-granular-request-validation-update.aspx did'nt knew about this feature. Also here : http://www.shamirc.com/2011/04/mvc3-xss-protection.html let me know when you find out and good luck!

Comment: The feature works good but seems like it does not work so good if the field being validated is an array :-( In that case the "allowhtml" does not seem to propagate down to the individual array elements and they still get validated. I wonder if this is a bug.

Comment: You don't need `ValidateInput[false]` if you use `AllowHtml` attribute on a property.